# Python code about converting to array

Tags: string, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a string in the form:

```
    expr="[[1,2,[numpy.sin(x),numpy.cos(x)]],[3,4,[numpy.sin(x)**2,numpy.cos(x)**2]]]"
```

I want to convert it to an array of the form:

```
    [["1","2",["numpy.sin(x)","numpy.cos(x)"]],["3","4",["numpy.sin(x)**2","numpy.cos(x)**2"]]]
```

How to do this? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only going by what you have there, your expression looks like it's just JSON.  Assuming future values of this sort stay that way, the `json` standard module should do what you need.  The values need to be quoted to make them strings, but otherwise the library can do most of the heavy lifting.

```
import re
import json

expr="[[1,2,[numpy.sin(x),numpy.cos(x)]],[3,4,[numpy.sin(x)**2,numpy.cos(x)**2]]]"

# Quote all the fields.
# expr        = [[1,2,[numpy.sin(x),...
# quoted_expr = [["1","2",["numpy.sin(x)",...
quoted_expr = re.sub(r'([^][,]+)([],])', r'"\1"\2', expr)

# Let the json library take care of the rest.
# my_array = [['1', '2', ['numpy.sin(x)', ...
my_array = json.loads(quoted_expr)
```